# why returned date from version history is different from actual date (triggerbody)

Tags: sharepoint-online, date-time, api, power-automate

It seems the SP data repository and front-end SP list use two different timezones. when I get a date from version history it is different from what is actually shown in the SP list, how can I fix this?

Below is the sample, "was" is coming from the data repository through version history API (_api/web/lists/getbytitle('')/items()/versions?$top=1), and "is" from the sp list through triggerbody().

[image]

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint stores dates in UTC, which are then converted to whatever time zone you have set for your site. In this case your date in UTC is the 27th but in your time zone is the 28th.